# How to unwobble a tyre

Tags: tire, wobble

I have a wobbling front tyre that I myself put on (it's a new one). I checked the rim and adjusted the spokes a bit and the rim appears to not be the issue, but the tyre is still wobbling.
I read online that this can happen to a tyre if it does not correctly sit "on the rim". I already deflated the tyre, massaged it a bit and inflated it again, but the issue persists.
I also read online that you lubricate the tyre so it will adjust itself, but it was recommended to get a special lubricant for that, as using oil or dish soap will stay on it and make the tyre slippery, possibly causing issues when breaking.

Asking around in local bike stores only yielded that they never heard of such a lubricant and it makes me wonder. How should I fix it myself (I don't want to bring it into a store).

Comment: Do you maybe have a (slow-mo) video that shows the wobbling? That could help identify the issue.

Comment: You're doing it right already - deflate, massage the tyre evenly onto rim, reinflate.   Did you have to stuff inner tube into the tyre?   Some tyres are just not-round from new, specially the very cheap wallmart grade ones.

Comment: Yes, I had to stuff it in there. I think the tyre was around 20€. Not sure if that is cheap. I can take a video later on.

Comment: 20€ can buy completely fine tires, but there are also places that charge that much for discount bin quality.

Comment: The tube may have folded over itself inside the tire, causing a portion to have three layers of inner tube.  That can produce a distorted tire when inflated.

Comment: The special tire lubricant is pretty much just dish soap. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Exactly. The seating lubricant could be washed away later by hosing the wheel with water, or just riding in a rain or through puddles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seated tire may wobble for these reasons.

1. Uneven rim. This is addressed by truing your wheel without the tire on it.
2. Uneven seating of the tire on the rim. Depending on the combination of tire/rim, this is likely the most probable/frequent cause. To help the tire to seat itself properly, try the following:

   1. deflate the tire;
   2. apply dish soap to both beads;
   3. "massage" the tire beads as you slowly inflate it to about ½ bar;
   4. continue to overinflate the tire somewhat (e.g. to the max recommended pressure specified on it);
   5. leave it stay so for about an hour;
   6. deflate it to the desired working pressure.
3. The tire itself is unevenly "baked". It is not unheard of to buy a tire from a faulty batch, which is then impossible to seat evenly no matter what you do. In this case, you should try returning it under warranty, it often works.

If you are stuck with an uneven tire on your hands, you should consider moving it to the back of the bicycle. Its unevenness will be less apparent there. This works better with large volume MTB tires, especially if you ride them offroad; maybe not so well with thin road bike tires on smooth asphalt stretches.

Answer (score 0):

There are special lubricants (e.g., Schwalbe markets "Easy Fit" liquid - https://www.schwalbe.com/en/zubehoer) that are supposed to help seat the beads and then evaporate without leaving a slippery smudge. Supposedly a bit better than the DIY solution of soapy water.

There are also special tools (e.g., Park Tool PTS-1 tire seater - https://www.parktool.com/en-int/product/tire-seater-pts-1) that literally grab the tire and seat it properly. They can scratch the sidewalls pretty badly though.

Comment: Personal experience: Schwalbe liquid didn't seem much different than soapy water. Tire seater scratches sidewalls (and can also scratch the rim if you are not careful - though the same can be said about tire levers), but the scratches are cosmetic and don't seem to be different from what I get from routine road and gravel mess.